# flutter force set a property value to all objects from a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list with custom objects and would like to iterate it and set the value to true/false.

Seen the `setAll` method but would be something like I don't change only a property of each object in the list.

My object looks something like:

```dart
class Feature {
  String id;
  String title;
  String subtitle;
  IconData leftIcon;
  IconData topRightIcon;
  IconData bottomRightIcon;
  bool isEnable;
  Feature({this.title, this.subtitle, this.leftIcon, this.topRightIcon, this.bottomRightIcon, this.isEnable,this.id});
}
```

So the object that would like to iterate would be: `List<Feature> features;`

How that's possible in flutter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you want to set `isEnable` to `false` for each `Feature` in a `List<Feature>` you can do the following:

```dart
features.forEach((f) => f.isEnable = false);
```

or

```dart
for (final f in features) {
  f.isEnable = false;
}
```